# Fast Testing: How to test Mailer without Loading Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, actionmailer

I've got some work to do refactoring a mailer class.  I don't want to spend all my time loading rails and waiting to see if tests are passing.  I'd like to just not include spec_helper and speed up my tests.

How do I just include ActionMailer?

I tried this:

```
require 'action_mailer'
```

but I stil end up with this error:

```
uninitialized constant ActionMailer (NameError)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you need to give a little more info here, especially which versions of Rails, RSpec, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using MiniTest, and the following works fine for me. You may be able to extrapolate from this, or provide some more info in your question.

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'mocha'
require "minitest-matchers"
require 'action_mailer'
require "email_spec"

require File.expand_path('../../../../app/mailers/my_mailer', __FILE__)

class MyMailerTest < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
  include EmailSpec::Helpers
  include EmailSpec::Matchers

  def test_it_is_sent_from_me
    email = MyMailer.refund_processed(42)
    email.must be_delivered_from("me@example.com")
  end
end
```